# KDE: Lock screen: Password box is only displayed after clicking mouse

Tags: kde, screen-lock

When locking the screen KDE shows a nice lock screen image. But it only shows a password box after pressing a mouse button.

I can also press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to make the box appear. If I then press <kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd> the focus is in the password box. This is a work-around, but sub-optimal.

I would like to have it show the password box with focus either all time or after pressing a key on the keyboard.

```
$ kdeinit5 --version
Qt: 5.12.8
KDE: 5.68.0
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS \n \l
```

Comment: Here (Debian, Qt 5.15.2 and KDE 5.78.0) the password box also appears on pressing a key (this key is already the first key of the password). And I'm pretty sure this is the case for many years and older Qt/KDE versions.

Comment: @Philippos It may very will be a config that is different. But which? I like your behaviour.

Comment: Manjaro, Qt: 5.15.3, KDE: 5.92.0 - the password box is displayed upon key presses as well. I checked ~/.config/kscreenlockerrc looking for a relevant setting, but I don't see any.

Comment: Can you try hitting Tab to see if it activates the password field? And if it doesn't become visible, does Tab and then password Enter work, even if it's invisible? Relevant bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=449857

Comment: I'm also facing this issue with Plasma 5.18.5, KDE 5.68.0, Qt 5.12.8 on Linux Mint 20.3. Did anyone manage to fix this?

Comment: Not sure what I have done, but now I have @Philippos behaviour.